# Using HTML5 canvas text - SEO consequences

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, seo

I'm building a website, where elements of the navigation bar are animated using HTML5's canvas element. for example, the buttons are floating circles. The idea is that the button's text will float to the right of these circles.
I'm wondering, in terms of SEO, what approach I should use to implement the different text elements:

One approach I think of is to just use canvas text to draw the text, but then of-course SEO can't read it. But I don't know - does Google's robots care about how I implement the navigation? Or maybe they just read the XML sitemap to understand it??

A second approach is to programmatically move html elements with the text using CSS, so that they will follow the animated circles.

A mixed approach I'm thinking of, is to draw on the canvas, but also to place the regular html navigation with regular text as the fallback content of the canvas.

As I'm not sure how Google's SEO works, I'd be happy if you share your opinion about the above approaches, or maybe offer a better one.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A second approach is to programmatically move html elements with the text using CSS, so that they will follow the animated circles.

That would be ideal from an SEO perspective as search engines will be able to crawl the content and follow your links while your users will get the benefit of the animation.

Comment: Thank you,
Won't they also crawl the fallback contents of the canvas? (The mixed approach)?

Comment: Because canvas is so new and dynamic I not optimistic that search engines can crawl it. But if you can use canvas with the CSS fallback that would be good for SEO as well.